# C# Linq - Cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable<string> to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List defined like this :

```
public List<string> AttachmentURLS;
```

I am adding items to the list like this:

```
instruction.AttachmentURLS = curItem.Attributes["ows_Attachments"].Value.Split(';').ToList().Where(Attachment => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Attachment));
```

But I am getting this error: Cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable to List

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try adding a type cast?
instruction.AttachmentURLS = (List<type, type>)curItem.Attributes...
  Oh of course, I forgot about the .ToList() method. Just add that to the end.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The Where method returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. Try adding

```
.ToList()
```

to the end like so:

```
instruction.AttachmentURLS = curItem.Attributes["ows_Attachments"]
  .Value.Split(';').ToList()
  .Where(Attachment => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Attachment))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I guess that means I can remove my existing .ToList from the middle of the statement?

Comment: Got this error, google'd it, apparently I've already upvoted it and been here before, I need more caffeine.

Answer (score 7):

Move the `.ToList()` to the end like this

```
instruction.AttachmentURLS = curItem
    .Attributes["ows_Attachments"]
    .Value
    .Split(';')
    .Where(Attachment => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Attachment))
    .ToList();
```

The Where extension method returns `IEnumerable<string>` and `Where` will work on arrays, so the `ToList` isn't needed after the `Split`.

Answer (score 2):

The `.ToList()` should be at last. Because in your code you perform the `.ToList()` operation earlier and after that again it goes to previous state. The Where method returns an IEnumerable.

Comment: why do you give the same answer eight hours after someone else did it?