# Linq Query for Year on a Date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my code in the controller:

```
}else if (reports == "Decommissioned")
            {
                if (reports != String.Empty)
                {
                    var date = (Convert.ToInt64(specific)) - 5;
                    desktop = desktop.Where(x => x.dt_date_delivered.Value.Year == date);
                    count = desktop.Where(x => x.dt_date_delivered.Value.Year == date).ToList().Count();
                }
            }
```

This query in inside a function in the controller. I wonder why is this not working where other controller where I did not put this query in the function, it works. When I try to run this code, the error is `Cannot implicity ceonvert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<InSys_Models.Desktop_reports_vw>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<InSys.Models.Desktop_reports_vw>'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Searching "Cannot implicitly convert `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`" gives plenty of results. Call `.ToList()` where you assign `desktop`.

Comment: `InSys_Models.Desktop_reports_vw` and `InSys.Models.Desktop_reports_vw` aren't same.

Comment: Just a Why can't you just use the following [Count()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) overload: `count = desktop.Count(x => x.dt_date_delivered.Value.Year == date);` to count your items?

Comment: Yes, there is no error in that line

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  Use copy+paste rather than retype otherwise typos look like the issue.  Most of your code is not relevant to the question (so getting comments/answers for the wrong issue).  It appears to boil down to one line for which you don't include the definitions.  A title that describes the problem would also help (eg Cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable to IList).

Comment: @Jen143Me - When looking at your code I thought you just wanted to count the elements, btw if include the line where `desktop` is declared, it will help

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Linq - Cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable<string> to List<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853647/c-sharp-linq-cannot-implicitly-convert-ienumerablestring-to-liststring)

Answer (score 2):

Because desktop.Where() function returns 'IEnumerable' you should call 'ToList()' to convert IEnumerable to List:

```
desktop = desktop.Where(x => x.dt_date_delivered.Value.Year == date).ToList();
```

Comment: Explain what you changed and why. "Try this" is not an answer.

Comment: I have this query above `var desktop = db.Desktop_reports_vw.Where(x => x.is_active == true).ToList();`

Comment: I didn't changed anything in my query except the fields name

Comment: OKay, thank you for this. But, after I run the code, i have this error "Nullable object must have a value."

Comment: Since, there are records in the database, the `dt_date_delivered` are NULL

Comment: You're checking nullable without checking if null `x => x.dt_date_delivered.Value.Year == date` should be `x => x.dt_date_delivered.HasValue && x.dt_date_delivered.Value.Year == date`

Answer (score 2):

You need to call ToList at the end of your Select in order to get back a list, instead of an IEnumerable.

Comment: Change From      desktop = desktop.Where(x => x.dt_date_delivered.Value.Year == date);  To  desktop = desktop.Where(x => x.dt_date_delivered.Value.Year == date).ToList();

Comment: Does it need that all data of `dt_date_delivered` has a value?

Comment: No need for all data of dt_date_delivered has a value

Comment: Then, why do I have an error like this `Nullable object must have a value.`?

Comment: You have to check first  nullable values in Linq                                                                           desktop = desktop.Where(x => x.dt_date_delivered.HasValue && x.dt_date_delivered.Value.Year == date).ToList();